# Finding the value of k in power of 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> A square matrix $A$ is said to be *orthogonal* if $A^TA = I = AA^T$. $P$ is an orthogonal matrix of order $3$ and $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are direction angles of a straight line. Let 
>   $$
> A = \begin{bmatrix}
> \sin^2 \alpha           & \sin \alpha \sin \beta & \sin \alpha \sin \gamma \\
> \sin \alpha \sin \beta  & \sin^2 \beta           & \sin \beta \sin \gamma \\
> \sin \alpha \sin \gamma & \sin \beta \sin \gamma & \sin^2 \gamma
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   and $Q = P^TAP$. Then, $PQ^6P^T = 2^k A, k = ?$

I am able to reduce it to $A^6$, but I don't understand how to reduce it to $A$.

Comment: Please transcribe the image into LaTeX. See [this tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if you need help.

Comment: yes. i am also not able to proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

You are correct, $Q^6 = A^6$ but if you define $\vec{v} = (\sin \alpha, \sin \beta, \sin \gamma)$ then $A = v^T v$ and $A^6 = \|v\|^{10} A$, now compute what is $\|v\|^2 = vv^T$ and simplify it using the fact that direction cosines satisfy
$$
\cos^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \beta + \cos^2 \gamma = 1.
$$

Comment: check A^2=2A. now you can solve.

Comment: @maveric it's a consequence of my hint, since $\|v\|^2=2$...